# Encryption on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, encryption

How can I make Debian encrypt and decrypt my home folder when I log in/out like Ubuntu does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setup for encrypted home folder is described here for Ubuntu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption

This should work on Debian as well, as Ubuntu is based on Debian.

However, you should consider whether full-disk encryption (i.e. encryption of / ) isn't more appropriate for you. Many programs will store personal data outside /home (e.g. /tmp, /var), plus swap will often also contain personal data leaked by swapping. So I'd advise to encrypt / and swap using LUKS. This is supported by the standard Debian installer; see the section in the [Debian installation guide](http://www.debian.org/releases/testing/i386/ch06s03.html.en#di-partition).

Answer (score -1):

You can setup decryption/encryption on login/logout for your home folder using the assisted configuration provided by ecryptfs-migrate-home as described here:

https://wiki.debian.org/TransparentEncryptionForHomeFolder#Assisted_configuration

Be sure to read the manpage carefully:

https://www.mankier.com/8/ecryptfs-migrate-home